# Как в Bootstrap выровнять форму по центру?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Как в Bootstrap выровнять форму и поле textarea по центру?

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <form style="max-width: 500px;"><textarea class="form-control"></textarea></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

m-auto
или d-flex, justify-content: center;

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте класс `justify-content-center` для `div` с классом `row` для того чтобы все вложенные `div` с классом `col` были выровнены по центру. Но для точного результата еще замените класс `col` на `col-6`, чтобы занять 50% ширины и выровнять их по центру

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <form style="max-width: 500px;"><textarea class="form-control"></textarea></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

P.S. [Вот ссылка](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/text/#text-alignment) на документацию